# MASM naming convention for identifiers beginning with a question mark?

Tags: assembly, naming-conventions, masm

Looking at the [BNF grammar for MASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-bnf-grammar?view=vs-2019), an identifier can be named as follows:

> The first character of the identifier can be an upper or lower-case
>   alphabetic character ([A–Za-z]) or any of these four characters: @ _ $
>   ? The remaining characters can be any of those same characters or a
>   decimal digit ([0–9]). Maximum length is 247 characters.

Are there any MASM (or assembly) naming conventions for beginning an identifier with a `?` (question mark) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any documented convention for leading ?s. But MASM appears to use two leading question marks when expanding macros that contain `LOCAL` labels.

This isn't clearly documented as a convention AFAIK, but the MASM Programmer's Guide kind of mentions it in passing in the section named *"Defining Local Symbols in Macros"*.

---

We can also test this ourselves by writing a simple piece of code:

```
.686
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

FOO MACRO
LOCAL local_to_foo
local_to_foo:
ENDM

.code

start:

FOO
FOO

END start
```

If we tell MASM to generate a listing file for this (with the `/Fl` option), the listing for the code section will look like this:

```
 00000000           .code

 00000000           start:

                FOO
 00000000            1  ??0000:
                FOO
 00000000            1  ??0001:

                END start
```

---

Bottom line is, it's probably best for you as a programmer to not use leading question marks in your identifiers, just like the MASM Programmer's Guide advises you not not use leading `@` characters since MASM uses that for some predefined special symbols.